# Laravel URL become localhost/index.php/login . How to change it back to localhost/login?

Tags: laravel, apache

I try to redirect my **localhost** to my laravel **project/public**
but the url become **localhost/index.php/login** instead of **localhost/login**

**my apache24/config/httpd :**

```
DocumentRoot "C:/AppServ/www/project/public"
<Directory "C:/AppServ/www/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**my apache24/config/extra/ httpd-vhosts :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\AppServ\www\project\public"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

**my project/public/.htaccess :**

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: What is `APP_URL` in `.env` file?

Comment: APP_URL=http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

Thank you , I found the answer!
I need to enable

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in httpd.conf